# Is there a word for sequences that are (proper) subsequences of themselves?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Is there a word for when a sequence $s$ is a proper subsequence of themselves, in the sense the sense that there is a (proper) subsequence of the naturals $a(n)$ such that $s(n)=s(a(n))$.

Examples (I've underlined the way in which the sequence is a subsequence of itself

- $1, \underline{1}, \underline{1}, \underline{1}, \underline{1}, \underline{1}, \dots$
- Any infinite sequence with finite range
- $1, \underline{1}, 2, \underline{1}, 3, \underline{2}, 4, \underline{1}, 5, \underline{3}, 6, \underline{2}, 7, \dots$
- $1, \underline{1}, 2, \underline{1}, \underline{2}, 3, \underline{1}, \underline{2}, \underline{3}, 4, \dots$

Nonexamples:

- $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \dots$ (since each number only occurs once, every number would need to be in the subsequence, which would make it improper)
- Any other sequence that does not repeat terms
- $3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, \dots$
- Finite sequences

Answer (score 5):

These are called [fractal sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_sequence).

Comment: Actually, fractal sequence seems to be more specific. I'm not sure though.